# NGINX Not Following Location

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

```
server {


listen 80;
    server_name *.bitmitigate.com bitmitigate.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        proxy_pass 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
  location / {
    return 302 https://bitmitigate.com;
  }
}
```

Essentially I want it to return 302 if it isn't matching that location, but for some reason it isn't working and always returns a 302

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.bitmitigate.com bitmitigate.com;

  location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    proxy_pass 
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
  location / {
    return 302 https://bitmitigate.com;
  }
}
```